# How to insert a percentage at specific positions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list

I'm trying to change the place of a `<div>` created by some Javascript code using `insertbefore()` but I don't understand how to apply it in my code.

My Javascript generate random numbers and create a `<div>` where these numbers are being inserted as childs of it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var orderedList = document.getElementById("my_list");
  var itemLength = orderedList.children.length - 1; // CALCULATE LENGTH OF THE ITEM LIST

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  // get a default 100 into the array
  var arrayOfNumbers = [100],
      listItem = document.querySelector("list_item");

  // get itemLength random numbers
  for (let i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {
    arrayOfNumbers.push(getRandomInt(30, 98))
  }

  // sort the array of random numbers
  arrayOfNumbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a
  })

  // now do the lopping and creating elements
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    let randomIntContainer = document.createElement('div');
    randomIntContainer.textContent = arrayOfNumbers[i] + "%";
    randomIntContainer.setAttribute('class', 'number');
    for (const matchingOrder of orderedList.querySelectorAll('.matching_score')) { matchingOrder.appendChild(randomIntContainer.cloneNode(true))}
  }

</script>
```

The problem is that the `<div>` with the numbers are being displayed at the end of my `<li>` element as you can see below:

```
<div>
   {% if  page_obj.object_list %}
       <ol class="row top20" id="my_list">

          {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

          <li class="list_item">
              <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
                      <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
                      <h5>{{ result.object.destination }}</h5>
                      <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
               </div>

          <!--  Numbers are displayed randomly here --> 90%

          </li>

           {% endfor %}

       </ol>
</div>
    {% endif %}
```

But I want this `<div>` and the numbers to be displayed above the `<a>` tag in a specific `<div>` with an Id of `matching_score` like this:

```
<div>
   {% if  page_obj.object_list %}
       <ol class="row top20" id="my_list">

          {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

          <li class="list_item">
              <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">

     <!--  Display the Js function in the written div below --> 

               <div class="matching_score">
                    <!-- Here -->
               </div>

               <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
                      <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
                      <h5>{{ result.object.destination }}</h5>
                      <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
               </div>
          </li>

           {% endfor %}

       </ol>
</div>
    {% endif %}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot have more than one element per page with any given `id`value. **Fix that first**, use `class` instead. Nobody wants to fix DOM stuff on invalid HTML.

Comment: _"The `Node.insertBefore()` method inserts a node before the reference node as a child of a specified parent node."_ (Source with examples: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore))

Comment: You've found the right method, did you try to use it? If so, show us what you tried and we can help you understand why it didn't work.

Comment: @connexo I change the code to have only one Id and change the Js to have querySelector instead of GetElementById but I don't get the numbers anymore..

Comment: An I get this error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

Comment: Now please clarify where **exactly** your div needs to be inserted.

Comment: I added these lines to my second html example to show where I want the div to be inserted:      `<!--  Display the Js function in the written div below --> 

               <div class="matching_score">
                    <!-- Here -->
               </div>`

Comment: That's still unclear, as there can be many list items since you are creating them in a `for` loop. You want the div to be inserted in each and every list item, or a specific one? If the latter, which one exactly?

Comment: In every list item

Comment: No use for insertBefore then. `for (const matchingOrder of orderedList.querySelectorAll('.matching_score')) { matchingOrder.appendChild(randomIntContainer.cloneNode(true)) }`

Comment: So I added this line inside of my loop (see the edited question) and the numbers are being diplayed at the right place but now the problem is that all the numbers are displayed and not just one by item, see the screenshot for reference: https://imgur.com/h2mgYvv

Comment: You need to work on very basic understanding of what you are doing. Isn't that obvious to you what's going on?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still learning. It might be obvious but I didn't find what's going on..

Comment: If it's displaying all the numbers within each item then it means that every time you loop to create an item you are also output all the numbers each time. If you want to only output one number within each item then you need to find a way to identify the specific number you need, based on the item you're currently outputting, and only select that one for output. How do you associate each number with each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    let randomIntContainer = document.createElement('div');
    randomIntContainer.textContent = arrayOfNumbers[i] + "%";
    randomIntContainer.setAttribute('class', 'number');
    for (const matchingOrder of orderedList.querySelectorAll('.matching_score')) { matchingOrder.appendChild(randomIntContainer.cloneNode(true))}
}
```

you need to do

```
for (const [i, matchingOrder] of orderedList.querySelectorAll('.matching_score').entries()) {
    let randomIntContainer = document.createElement('div');
    randomIntContainer.textContent = arrayOfNumbers[i] + "%";
    randomIntContainer.className = 'number';
    matchingOrder.appendChild(randomIntContainer);
}
```

Example to prove it's working:

```js
let arrayOfNumbers = [ 2,5,6,8 ];

for (const [i, matchingOrder] of orderedList.querySelectorAll('.matching_score').entries()) {
  let randomIntContainer = document.createElement('div');
  randomIntContainer.textContent = arrayOfNumbers[i] + "%";
  randomIntContainer.className = 'number';
  matchingOrder.appendChild(randomIntContainer);
}
```

```html
<ol id="orderedList">
  <li>
    <div class="matching_score"></div>
    <p>Foo</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="matching_score"></div>
    <p>Bar</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="matching_score"></div>
    <p>Baz</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="matching_score"></div>
    <p>Foobar</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I get this in the console when I add this code: `Uncaught TypeError: matchingOrder.appendChild is not a function`

Comment: In what browser?

Comment: I use Google Chrome

Comment: My bad, it's got to be `[i, matchingOrder]` and not `[matchingOrder, i]`. Retry please.

Comment: It works now, thank you so much! I really appreciate that!